# Add text with plain and italic font to plot

Tags: r

On Kaplan Meier plots, how can model statistics be added (E.g. "HR: 0.79 *P*=0.13") with numbers extracted from an object and *P* in italic?

Among many unsuccessful things, I have tried the code below (plot and numbers simplified).

```
plot(1)

text(x=1, y=0.8, expression(paste("HR: ",round(runif(1),2),italic("P"),"=", round(runif(1),2))))
```

Expected result: HR: 0.79 *P*= 0.01

Actual result: HR: round(runif(1),2) *P*= round(runif(1),2)

Answer (score 0):

This post gives a very good solution https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Using-expression-for-Italics-and-object-evaluation-in-plot-title-td836686.html

```
plot(1)

text(x=1, y=0.8, bquote("HR:" ~ .(round(runif(1),2)) ~ italic("P") * "=" * .(round(runif(1),2))))
```